# File upload to google bucket works from localhost but fails in production

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to upload files to Google Bucket. Everything works fine when I run the application in my local server. I have a tomcat instance in google compute engine. If I deploy the war file to the tomcat instance, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
```

Here is the root cause:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
com.google.api.gax.retrying.BasicRetryingFuture.<init>(BasicRetryingFuture.java:77)
com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:75)
com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:53)
com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:148)
com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:141)
```

I have no idea what's going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: NoSuchMethodError is most often caused by missing or wrong versions of classes. Can you share your pom file or however you are building the WAR?

Comment: Thanks @David. That was a version error. I've updated my pom and it works fine now.